# French characters applemac not working

Tags: french

I'm completely new here, and trying LaTeX to write my PhD dissertation (in the humanities, mind you!). I have to write in several languages, and especially French. It is therefore much easier to type the French characters directly on the keyboard. I have a mac with OS 10.8.5. I used the tip given here on the Tex stack exchange (\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}) and it worked really fine. But, now it suddenly does not work any more without me touching anything when I run it in PDF.
I set the following in my configuration:

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}             

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}       

 \setdefaultlanguage[british,ordinalmonthday=true]{english}
 \setotherlanguage[spelling=old,latesthyphen=true,babelshorthands=true]{german}
 \setotherlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{italian}
 \usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[style=british,autostyle=true,strict=true,english=british,autopunct=true,parthreshold=true,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{british}
\SetBlockThreshold{3}
```

Comment: Never use `inputenc` with xetex or luatex (which you must be using as you use `fontspec` Just make sure that you save your file in utf-8 and the characters will work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The code snippets you've provided don't generate the problems you're describing. Please edit your code to make into an MWE (minimum working example) that illustrates the points you're trying to fix. Also, please indicate which editor(s) you use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why don't you write an answer up? :)

Comment: @MarioS.E. I was looking for a duplicate question

Comment: Thank you very much. Getting rid of the `inputenc` command has fixed the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you have a dupe in mind/at hand?